# how to give a Shadow to DrawerLayout but from left to right gradient?

Tags: android, shadow

I am using a Navigation Drawer in my Android Project i successfully implemented it but now i want a shadow on drawer layout which have to display from left to right.

This is my Drawer shadow Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
       android:endColor="#00000000"
       android:startColor="#111" >
   </gradient>

   <size
       android:height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:width="25px" >
   </size>
```

Comment: I think you forgot something.

Comment: i want to add a image to show you example but dont have much reputation to upload or give  a image lnk :-(

Comment: @Sam upload pic in http://tinypic.com/ and add link as text. :)

Comment: This seems odd. You just want to flip the gradient horizontally? Won't that look weird? (Unless you mean it's for a right-hand drawer.) If that is what you want, just swap `endColor` and `startColor`.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=116j408&s=8      Shadow example

Comment: I found a new way just remove setDrawerShadow method and add a image view in android layout and its working awsome ....